# how to send checkbox value in listview to next activity on android

Tags: checkbox

i want to pass the value of checkbox in listview to the next activity.The next activity will be android json parsing activity that will get the value of checkbox.the question is how to pass checkbox value?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class Item extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    String [] builder;
    Button button;
    ListView listView;
    String [] array = new String[] {"Baby Cot ", "Bouncer", "Bottle", "Blanket", "Stroller", "Toy", "Walker", "Thermal Bag", "Storage Bag", "Diaper", "Pacifier", "Potty", "Baby Bath" , "Baby CD", "Baby Book", "Car Seat", "Teethers", "Cooler Bag", "High Chair", "Apparel"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main1);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, array);

       listView =  (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
       listView.setAdapter(adapter);
       listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

       button = (Button) findViewById (R.id.testbutton);
       button.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        SparseBooleanArray positions = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();

        for (int index = 0; index <array.length; index++){

            if (positions.get (index) == true)
            {
                builder[index] = array[index];

            }
        }

        Intent i = new Intent(this, AndroidJSONParsingActivity.class);
        Bundle  b = new Bundle();
        b.putStringArray("list", builder);
        i.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(i);


        }


        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3){

        }




    }
```

Comment: You're missing a few things: 1) code you've written, 2) research you've already done, and 3) an actual question.

Comment: there is a missing in this code?

Comment: `there is a missing in this code?` Not anymore! Looks like you updated your question after I posted my comment, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you pass parameters to the next intent. (Assuming your value was stored in a variable named "checkboxValue")

Obviously, change NextActivity.class to your activity name.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("key", 1); //Your checkbox value
intent.putExtras(b); //Put your checkbox to your next Intent
startActivity(intent);
```

Access it by this code in your new activity:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
int value = b.getInt("key");
```

I hope this helps.